# Redeclare block-scoped variable allowed when exporting

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to gain a better understanding of type declarations and one thing that trips me up is this simple example.

```
declare type Element = {
  one: string;
}


declare const Element: {two: string}; <- Error: Cannot redeclare block-scoped variable 'Element'.
```

vs.

```
export declare type Element = {
  one: string;
}


declare const Element: {two: string}; // <- No Error when export
```

I'm not sure why I'm allowed to redeclare a variable when using a declare statement. Without the declare statement is does not work.